# Why can't apt resolve names?

Tags: networking, apt, updates

Like [a bunch of other questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845913/apt-get-update-not-working-and-i-cant-add-any-repositories?noredirect=1&lq=1), I can't run `apt-get update` *sometimes*. Restarting or waiting for a while makes the problem go away. I never have issues pinging or visiting the respective URLs in a browser.

I've tried every up-voted answer to no avail. What is `apt` doing that is so different to `ping` or my browser? For example, when I run `apt-get update` I see this:

```
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve host: download.docker.com
Err:2 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease
  Could not resolve host: deb.opera.com
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/myppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
  Could not resolve 'repository.spotify.com'
Err:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve host: download.docker.com
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve host: deb.opera.com
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/saiarcot895/myppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'repository.spotify.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Running `ping download.docker.com`:

```
PING d2h67oheeuigaw.cloudfront.net (52.85.41.233) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server-52-85-41-233.mel50.r.cloudfront.net (52.85.41.233): icmp_seq=1 ttl=251 time=18.8 ms
64 bytes from server-52-85-41-233.mel50.r.cloudfront.net (52.85.41.233): icmp_seq=2 ttl=251 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from server-52-85-41-233.mel50.r.cloudfront.net (52.85.41.233): icmp_seq=3 ttl=251 time=19.5 ms
```

And visiting the page in my browser works fine. How can I make `apt-get` "just work"?

Here is the contents of my `/etc/apt/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home.gateway
```

Comment: try `apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update`

Comment: Does /etc/apt/apt.conf exist and if so, is it using a proxy?  A quick fix would be to add the lookup info for those servers in /etc/hosts.  The down side of that approach would be if the IPs of those servers ever changes.

Comment: @jones0610 it exists. Why can't apt just resolve hostnames like any other applicaton?

Comment: @Arun that first one seems to work. Why is that?

Comment: @arman I "think" it gets created if, at some point, you connect the machine to a proxy server.  I've seen this problem before and the addition of apt.conf becomes permanent.  I "think" you can safely rename it which should solve your problem.  Or make a copy of it and edit the original, commenting out the proxy line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command from terminal and you could use `apt` and `apt-get` normally in the future :)

```
echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

Comment: do you know the underlyig problem? why does ipv6 not work?

Answer (score 1):

If `/etc/atp/apt.conf` exists, make a copy of the file and then edit the original to comment out the following line (if not behind a proxy server):

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyaddress:proxyport";
```