# How to resolve the many errors when updating

Tags: package-management, updates, security

I opened my terminal and saw this:
[updates message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QayPG.png)

So I then I tried updating and upgrading but got many errors. I looked on this forum for similar situation and tried their suggested solutions, however it did not resolve my issue.

Is there any advice on what to do?

This is a screenshot of the errors I got: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTfHt.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't apt resolve names?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926302/why-cant-apt-resolve-names)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you tried that didn't work...and where you found those answers that didn't work.